# Can you enter UK later than intended date of travel on the visa application?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, filipino-citizens

If I apply in December to travel in March, and I am granted the visa, what happens if something comes up (emergency, work etc.) and I have to postpone the trip?

Will I still be allowed to enter the UK, even if I arrive after my intended travel dates?

Answer (score 6):

You are asking about this page of the application form...

[image]

This is strictly *indicative information* that they use to help understand the other parts of your application. It has *no other value* once a visa has been issued.

The actual start and end dates of your visa are printed on the visa itself and travel between those dates (inclusively) is fine.

---

NOTE: if the form you are filling out does NOT look like the one above, then you are filling out the wrong form.  For the remainder of 2017, the starting page for a Standard Visitor Visa is at https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa