# UK tourist visa- Validity start date and end date for (6 months family and tourist visa)

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

Please share your experience.

I am planning to apply UK family and tourist visa (6 months visa).

Lets say on the application form my intended Entry date in UK is 15 NOV 2019 and Exit date is 05 DEC 2019 and I have visa interview on 23 AUG 2019.

1- In case of my visa approval what time frame will be stamped on my visa (like start date and End date)

2- As stated on GOV.UK, visa review time is approximately 3 weeks (for no other problems with the application/docs), the issue date would be same as the start date of visa validity?

3- Can we request the visa officers during the interview of any specific time period of the visa.

As such I do have a specific plan but in case if it changes for any uncertain reasons.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 2):

The standard validity period for a UK visitor visa for tourism purposes is 6 months. The start date is usually the intended date of travel as stated in the application or the date of issue [Can you enter UK later than intended date of travel on the visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100403/can-you-enter-uk-later-than-intended-date-of-travel-on-the-visa-application/100407#100407)

The UK advises against booking travel before receiving the visa decision, and it is not a requirement to submit evidence of travel arrangements with an application.